# milter-regex / Ubuntu or Debian

Tags: debian, sendmail, milter

I have been using milter-regex (http://www.benzedrine.cx/milter-regex.html) on Redhat for some time and am moving to Ubuntu.

When compiling the source from their website, I get errors, even though I have the required libs installed.  The email address on their site bounces back so I cannot subscribe to their mailing list.

- Is anyone here subscribed?
- Has anyone been able to compile v1.7?
- Does anyone know of a deb package for milter-regex 1.7?

Thanks......
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

- Download latest rpm
- Convert to deb via alien
- Install
- Create start up script via the skeleton file in /etc/init.d